# An inverse Laplace transform and its asymptotics

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I am wondering if there is an analytic expression for the inverse Laplace transform $f(t):=\mathcal L^{-1}[F](t)$ for $F(s):=\frac1{s(\cosh{\sqrt{2s}}-1)}$. If there is no such analytic expression, what would be an asymptotics of $f(t)$ for $t\to\infty$?

Comment: Heuristically, to find the asymptotics of $f(t)$ at $t\to\infty$ we have to investigate the asymptotics of $F(s)$ at $s\to0$:
$$F(s\to0)\sim\frac1{s^2}\,\Rightarrow\,f(t)\sim t$$

Comment: $\cosh(\sqrt{2s})=1+s+\frac{4s^2}{4!}+...\,$ is an analytical and single-valued function in all complex plane, so we can try to close the contour by an arch (radius $R\to\infty$) and use the residue theorem.

Comment: @Hans Did any of us answer your question?

Comment: @Gary: Yes, I think both of you did. Thank you both. I have been busy and have an equivalent approach that I would like to write out. I also need some time to check the details of all these answers. I will accept one of the answers soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that \begin{align*}
F(s) &= \frac{1}{{s(\cosh (\sqrt {2s} ) - 1)}}  = \frac{1}{{2s}}{\mathop{\rm csch}\nolimits} ^2\! \left( {\sqrt {\frac{s}{2}} } \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{{s^2 }} + \frac{2}{s}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{s + 2\pi ^2 n^2 }}}  - \frac{{8\pi ^2 }}{s}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{n^2 }}{{(s + 2\pi ^2 n^2 )^2 }}} .
\end{align*}
(This is a re-written form of [$(4.36.4)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.36.E4).) Hence,
$$
f'(t) = \mathscr{L}^{ - 1} (sF(s)) = 1 + 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{\rm e}^{ - 2\pi ^2 n^2 t} }  - 8\pi ^2 t\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n^2 {\rm e}^{ - 2\pi ^2 n^2 t} } ,
$$
and therefore
$$
f(t) = t - \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{{\pi ^2 }}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}{\rm e}^{ - 2\pi ^2 n^2 t} }  + 4t\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{\rm e}^{ - 2\pi ^2 n^2 t} } ,
$$
provided $\operatorname{Re}(t)>0$. The constant $-\frac{1}{6}$ follows from
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{s \to 0^ +  } s\!\left( {F(s) - \frac{1}{{s^2 }}} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to  + \infty } (f(t) - t).
$$
This is a consequence of the [final value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem).

Comment: Slick solution. However, can you justify the interchanging of the inverse Laplace transform and the infinite sum?

Comment: @Hans It is easy to see that the series are uniformly convergent when $\mathrm{Re}(s)>0$ (Weierstrass M-test).

Answer (score 7):

The function has second order poles along the negative real axis at $s =  -2\pi^2k^2$ for $k\in\Bbb{Z}$. By the [Final Value Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem) we have that

$$\lim_{s\to0^+}s^2F(s) = 1 = \lim_{t\to\infty}f'(t)$$

and

$$\lim_{s\to0^+}s\left(F(s)-\frac{1}{s^2}\right) = \lim_{s\to0^+}\frac{1}{s}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{6}s+\frac{1}{90}s^2+\cdots}-1\right) = -\frac{1}{6} = \lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)-t$$

The inverse Laplace transform of each of the other second order poles is

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{F(s)+\frac{1}{6s}-\frac{1}{s^2}\right\} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(4t+\frac{1}{\pi^2k^2}\right)e^{-2\pi^2k^2t}$$

by the Residue theorem

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-i\infty}^{+i\infty}e^{st}\left(F(s)+\frac{1}{6s}-\frac{1}{s^2}\right)ds = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\operatorname{Res}\left(e^{st}\left(F(s)+\frac{1}{6s}-\frac{1}{s^2}\right),s=-2\pi^2k^2\right)$$

$$ = \sum_{k=1}^\infty-\frac{e^{-2\pi^2k^2t}}{2\pi^2k^2}\left(t+\frac{1}{2\pi^2k^2}\right)\cdot\lim_{s\to-2\pi^2k^2}\frac{(s+2\pi^2k^2)^2}{\cosh\sqrt{2s}-1}$$

$$-\frac{e^{-2\pi^2k^2t}}{2\pi^2k^2}\cdot\lim_{s\to-2\pi^2k^2}\left(\frac{(s+2\pi^2k^2)^2}{\cosh\sqrt{2s}-1}\right)'$$

which can be evaluated by using

$$\lim_{s\to-2\pi^2k^2}\frac{(s+2\pi^2k^2)^2}{\cosh\sqrt{2s}-1} = -8\pi^2k^2$$

and

$$\lim_{s\to-2\pi^2k^2}\left(\frac{(s+2\pi^2k^2)^2}{\cosh\sqrt{2s}-1}\right)' = \frac{8\pi^2k^2}{4\pi^2k^2}=2$$

This gives us a final answer for the inverse Laplace transform of $F$ itself as

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{s(\cosh\sqrt{2s}-1)}\right\} = t - \frac{1}{6} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(4t+\frac{1}{\pi^2k^2}\right)e^{-2\pi^2k^2t}$$

Comment: It should be $-\frac{1}{6}=\lim_{t\to \infty}(f(t)-t)$.

Comment: @Gary thank you yes you're right, I have fixed it and added the computation for the real residue.

Comment: Nice solution. However, when you turn the infinite integral into the infinite sum of residues, you have to show the contour integral at infinity vanishes, right?

Comment: Are you able to prove the part of the contour at infinity vanish as I asked in the last comment?